# Do global aliases exist in bash

Tags: bash, alias

I wonder if it is possible to set a "global" alias in bash, like zsh's ***-g*** alias option - not "global" from the user's point of view but from the shell's point of view.

What I want to know is: Can an alias (or something else?) be substituted anywhere on a line in bash?

e.g..:

```
alias ...='../..'
```

Comment: Note that `...` is a perfectly valid filename, so this may not be a great idea if you have a world-writable directory (e.g. accessible via anonymous FTP).

Comment: Thanks Kevin but that's just an exemple

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the `bash(1)` man page:

```
ALIASES 
  Aliases allow a string to be substituted for a word when it is used  as
  the  first  word  of  a  simple command. [...]
```

So `bash` aliases do not have this capability, nor does `bash` have a trivial `pre-exec` capability (but [see here](https://superuser.com/questions/175799/does-bash-have-a-hook-that-is-run-before-executing-a-command) for a hack though).

As a *partial* workaround you may be able to use a *completion* function, here's a minimal starting point:

```
function _comp_cd() {
    local cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]} # the current token
    [[ $cur =~ \.\.\. ]] && {
        cur=${cur/.../..\/..}
        COMPREPLY=( $cur )
        return
    }
    COMPREPLY=()    # let default kick in
}

complete -o bashdefault -o default -F _comp_cd cd
```

Now when you hit tab on a `cd` command and the word under the cursor contains "...", each will be replaced with "../..". Completion suffers from a slight problem too though (excluding its complexity) which you can probably guess from the above, you need to specify it on a command by command basis.

The [bash-completion package](https://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/) uses a default completion handler, with on-the-fly loading of completion functions to deal with this. If you're feeling adventurous you should be able to modify its internal function `_filedir()` function which is used for general file/directory expansion so as to include a similar substitution "...".

(All of which reminds of the NetWare shell, which made "..." Just Work.)

Answer (score 7):

Bash aliases do not have this capability, but you can write:

```
alias cd='cd '
alias ...='../..'
cd ... # teleport to ../..
```

**Explanation:**

[Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases) says:

> If the last character of the alias value is a blank, then the next command word following the alias is also checked for alias expansion.

Possible solution is a `Readline`'s macro. You can write:

```
set -o emacs
bind '"\C-x...":"cd ../.."'
```

Type `echo`,<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>,<kbd>.</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>

You should see `echo cd ../..`

See

- "Key Bindings" in [Readline Init File Syntax](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Readline-Init-File-Syntax)
- `help bind`

Answer (score 4):

bash aliases only work based on the first word on the line and can not be defined in a global sense like zsh.

The only fudge I can think of would be to define a variable e.g.

```
export PP=../..  # $PP meaning parent of parent
cd $PP/anotherDirectory
```

But to be honest I would prefer to just type ../.. in that case. In short bash does not do it.

Comment: Thanks nice answer, workaround included, maybe bash should stay bash

Comment: not only on the first word: see my [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/217102/120177)