# Using multiple alias in a single command

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, macos, google-cloud

I'm facing problem in using multiple alias in a single line on `Mac` `bash` `Terminal`.
I have setup below alias in my `.bash_profile` file

```
alias gc=gcloud
alias cmp=compute
alias ins=instances
alias pdev="--project=devproj-12891"
function listgce(){
    gcloud compute instances list --project "$1"
}
```

all those are available as alias individually and can be used but when I try to use multiple of these on a single command, bash evaluates to only first one.
Example :

```
~ % gc cmp ins list pdev
ERROR: (gcloud) Invalid choice: 'cmp'.
Maybe you meant:
  gcloud compute instances
```

Can please someone guide me if I'm doing something wrong in this ?

Comment: Related: [Do global aliases exist in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216414/do-global-aliases-exist-in-bash)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible in bash: if the last character of an alias definition is a space (or tab), then bash will unalias the *next word* too:

```bsh
$ alias foo="echo "
$ alias bar="hello "
$ alias baz=world
$ foo bar baz
hello world
```

Ref: [6.6 Aliases](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases) in the manual.

So you can chain aliases together: but the first word must be an alias.

---

I would not use aliases though: it's quite subtle and probably brittle. I'd use a function, something like

```bsh
gc() {
    local -A translation=(
        [cmp]=compute
        [ins]=instances
        [pdev]="--project=devproj-12891"
    )
    local -a args
    for arg in "$@"; do
        if [[ -v "translation[$arg]" ]]; then
            args+=("${translation[$arg]}")
        else
            args+=("$arg")
        fi
    done
    echo gcloud "${args[@]}"
}
```

Then

```bsh
$ gc cmp ins list pdev
gcloud compute instances list --project=devproj-12891
```

Remove the `echo` if it looks good.

---

Update to address shortcut "ci" adding 2 words "compute" "instances":

This is a special case because we don't want to add one single quoted item to the args, but two. Let me rewrite that function for greater extensibility:

```bsh
gc() {
    local -a args
    for arg in "$@"; do
        case $arg in
            cmp)  args+=( compute ) ;;
            ins)  args+=( instances ) ;;
            ci)   args+=( compute instances ) ;;
            pdev) args+=( "--project=devproj-12891" );;
            *)    args+=( "$arg" ) ;;
        esac
    done
    echo gcloud "${args[@]}"
}
```

Comment: This is awesome , thanks

Comment: I want to add another shortcut "ci" for "compute instances" 
but when I add that and run the gcloud command, it throws me an error : 

2LKMD6R ~ % g ci list poc               
list
project poc has been set
compute instances list --project=poc-proj-123
ERROR: (gcloud) Invalid choice: 'compute instances'.
Maybe you meant:
  gcloud compute instances

However, if I pass it as two arguments `c` and `i` , it translates to two argument and the command works fine

is there some trick to add two words together ?

Comment: Added an update to my answer. See how it's more flexible?

Comment: Thanks very much Glenn .
Other approach I found to original solution is to split words at white space 
args+=($=translation[$arg])

Comment: `$=`? are you using zsh?

Comment: I'm mainly using bash but I was trying to make it work on mac terminal too to share it with everyone. 
Sorry, I should have mentioned that too

Comment: Be aware that bash and zsh are different languages. bash will not understand `$=translation[$arg]`. Be sure to use the appropriate shebang for your scripts.