# Bash equivalent of zsh alias at end of command (for pipes)

Tags: bash, shell-script, zsh, pipe

In zsh, I can set an alias at the end of a command, e.g. making `G` pipe through grep or `L` pipe through less.

Can I do something similar in bash? E.g. `ls G key` would expand to `ls | grep key` or `ls L` would do `ls | less`.

Comment: Possibly related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/217102

Comment: note that in case of `ls` then you should use `ls *key*` rather than `ls | grep key`. It's both shorter and more correct. And also slightly faster

Comment: @phuclv, that should be `ls -d -- *key*`, or `print -rC1 -- *key*(N)` (zsh) to avoid the error if there's no match (and avoid `ls` which is pointless in that case as the listing is done by shell globbing).